# How can i call two javascript function from c# page both on button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

```
 btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "return Getprodsize('" + hdnprdsize.ClientID + "')";
 btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "return formatSpecifications('" + hdnSpecifications.ClientID + "')";
```

Only one function is called it ignores the other i need both the functions to be called on button click.

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "Getprodsize('" + hdnprdsize.ClientID + "');return formatSpecifications('" + hdnSpecifications.ClientID + "')";
```

> To ensure that both functions are called .. discard first function return checking

Answer (score 0):

How about add a middle function to wrap both functions up?

```js
function MiddleWare(hdnprdsizeClientID,  hdnSpecificationsClientID){
    Getprodsize(hdnprdsizeClientID);
    formatSpecifications(hdnSpecificationsClientID);
}
```

```html
btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "return MiddleWare('" + hdnprdsize.ClientID +",'" + hdnSpecifications.ClientID + "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t do anything this return values :

```
btnSubmit.OnClientClick = "function () { Getprodsize('" + hdnprdsize.ClientID + "');formatSpecifications('" + hdnSpecifications.ClientID + "');return true; }";
```